# Linq Query for matching

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Linq to return a list that is sorted by items that are matched most to least.

I have a string of "relevant tags" or "keywords" delimited by ";" :

a;b;c;d;e;f;g

I have a record A in the database that has

a;b;c;d;e;f;g

I have another record B in the database that has 
a;b;c;

I want to search the database using linq and return 
a list where record A is first in the list and record B would be the second.

Tried:

```
dbContext2.Mains.where(x => x.VideoID == VideoID.ToString())
                .where( x=> x.Tags.Contains(ListOfKeyWords))
                .single();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to return a list where record A is first because it simply has more 'tags'?

Comment: @sr28  Simply because it has MATCHED more tags. Yes thank you! :)

Comment: You want to "return a list" yet your code ends with `.single();`. Also, your code won't compile anyway since `Where` and `Single` should start with a capital letter. Anyway, solving this with LINQ is going to be hard; even doing this in SQL wouldn't be easy.

Comment: @Coder1409 Basically i'm trying to find records that match the most keywords. I want to return a sorted list top to bottom

Comment: @BCdotWEB I've been spending hours on this I know that query doesn't make sense It was one of my attempts my better attempt I deleted it out of frustration.

Comment: Ok, so it's just the tags that matter and not the VideoID? Are you saying you want to return a list of VideoID's where they match most tags that have been supplied in ListOfKeyWords?

Comment: what's videoId for is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Can a VideoID have more than 1 entry? So could I find a VideoID with a record with 'a;b;c' as its tags and then the same VideoID with 'a;b;c;d;e' as it's tags for example, or is there only 1 entry per VideoID?

Comment: @sr28 VideoID is just how i'm matching the record. 

- > User selects video. I extract "Video ID" 

- I search DB for VIDEOID check the tags that are associated with it 
which is a string that looks like this: "youtube;awesome;video;stuff; 

then I search the Database for any video that matches those tags 
so if I find a video that matches all four of those tags I want it to be at the top of the list. If I find a video that matches 3 of those tags I want that to be second on the list and so on.

Comment: @Coder1409 It's the video that the user selects. Then I look at the video's tags and try to find related "videoIDs" that match the tags of the first video the user selected. Does this make sense bud?

Comment: @Coder1409 the VideoID is what I'm given when a user selects a video. I look at it's "tag" column in the database to then search the database for other videos that might match those tags, the more tags I match the more relevant that video is. 

So the situation is that I'm trying to get a list back that has been populated with the most relevant videoids so when the user clicks "next video" button it will display the next most relevant video.

Comment: First, as you described i don't see any use for the first condition .Since you can't do use custom comparers with EF , if the list of the videos isn't too big , you can load them first to memory and sort them using a custom comparer

Answer (score 0):

We can start by formulating a method that will give a score to a string of *tags*:

```
public int GetScore(string contentTags, IEnumerable<string> relevantTags) {
      int score = 0;
      string[] splittedTags = contentTags.split(';');
      for(int i = 0; i < splittedTags.Length; i++) {
           if(relevantTags.Contains(splittedTags[i])) {
                score++;
           }
      }
      return score;
}
```

According to your question, you have a similar class to this one:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
      public DbSet<Main> Mains { get; set; }
}
```

To get an ordered list of your `Main` records given a relevance score, you might do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Main> records = myContext.Mains.OrderByDescending(x => GetScore(x.Tags, ListOfKeywords));
```

Comment: I m not sure if this can be translated to SQL , he is using EF so must check it out, otherwise he could've simply implement IComparable interface